# how to remove "Warning: Failed to set locale category ... " on neovim opening?

Tags: neovim

```
Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_NUMERIC to en_IT.
Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_TIME to en_IT.
Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_COLLATE to en_IT.
Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_MONETARY to en_IT.
Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_MESSAGES to en_IT.
Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_NUMERIC to en_IT.
Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_TIME to en_IT.
Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_COLLATE to en_IT.
Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_MONETARY to en_IT.
Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_MESSAGES to en_IT.
```

Answer (score 5):

If to add in .bash_profile, .zprofile:

```
#Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_*** to en_UA.
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

then also the following command will show the resulting output:

```
locale
```

Comment: I was facing this problem for over now a year and finally, this is the answer that helped me. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest running Neovim with an empty config:

```
vim -u NONE
```

Then see if this behavior is still there. If it is, there may be something wrong with your Neovim installation or file system.

If the problem vanishes, comment out all plugins and autocmds and re-enable them one by one. Rinse and repeat until you hit the problem again. You will then have found the setting or plugin causing it.